# Pandas compare one column from df1 with multiple columns in df2

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 df.

df1 has records of actions performed by users, and df2 has actions owned by users. compare particular action field with its respective owner field and flag with boolean value. Can this be done without using loops for each filed and action for user. Please help!!

df1 =

```
 owner    field           value
0   Rick      cin          234011
1  Daryl    email  test@gmail.com
2  Negan    phone         9087654
3  Carol  address         Hilltop
```

df2 =

```
   owner      cin             email    phone     address
0   Rick   543216  test@hotmail.com  9654356  Alexandria
1  Daryl   675432    test@gmail.com  9876590     kingdom
2  Negan   234123    test@yahoo.com  9087654  Ocean side
3  Carol  0987809   test2@gmail.com  9076535     Atlanta
```

Expected Result =

```
owner      field    value           Flag
0   Rick    cin     234011          False
1   Daryl   email   test@gmail.com  True
2   Negan   phone   9087654         True
3   Carol   address Hilltop         False
```

Since Daryl and Negan owns those entities, we flagged them true.
I have tried using merge and getting the identical entities but it needs to be looped across all fields and values.

Any help is appreciated Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Melt df1 :

```
    df1_melt = (
    df1.melt(["owner", "field"])
    .drop("variable", 1)
    .rename(columns={"field": "variable"})
)
df1_melt

owner   variable    value
0   Rick    cin 234011
1   Daryl   email   test@gmail.com
2   Negan   phone   9087654
3   Carol   address Hilltop
```

Melt df2, merge with df1_melt, and finally rename and change values in Flag to True/False :

```
    (
    df2.melt("owner")
    .astype(str)
    .merge(df1_melt, how="right", indicator=True)
    .rename(columns={"_merge": "Flag"})
    .assign(Flag=lambda x: np.where(x.Flag == "both", True, False))
)



   owner    variable    value           Flag
0   Rick    cin       234011            False
1   Daryl   email     test@gmail.com    True
2   Negan   phone     9087654           True
3   Carol   address   Hilltop           False
```